# Batchfiles with caret line breaks without Word wrap

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-xp

In Windows batch files the carriage return is possible to
be done with a soft break a automatic Word wrap in the 
view command of the Editor program.
When i use a hard break with the return key and the soft
break, the automatic Word wrap is turned off, not sheduled
or marked, a filepath or filepathname is not validated
through CMD command line.

For example:

```
type C:\"Dokumente und Einstellungen"\Textdokument.txt
```

returns the output from a Textfile.

```
type C:\"Dokumente und Einstellungen"
\Textdokument.txt
```

wrapped with the return key, does not return a output.
The same command with the filename

```
type C:\"Dokumente und Einstellungen"
\Textdokument.txt
```

returns the output from a Textfile, when the Word wrap is
on and breaks the line without that i use the return key.
In which way the line is broken depends on the size of the
opened Editor window.

When the Word wrap is again turned off, i can use a caret
symbol ^ to break the line instead of using the automatic
line break, the soft break which is the Word wrap command
turned on.

```
type C:\"Dokumente und Einstellungen"^
\Textdokument.txt
```

returns the output from a Textfile even if the automatic
line break, the  Word wrap was turned off while the TEXT
was written.

With s `for /F` command and `"usebackq"` option, because of the
double quotes i have to use for my NTFS formated harddrive,
the TEXT in the command line is

```
for /F "usebackq" %%A in ("C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Textdokument.txt") do echo %%A
```

which echos the Textfile.

It is also possible to break the line with Word wrap on.
That returns a output.

And like with the type command when the Word wrap is off,
there is no return output from the Textfile with with a
broken line in the filepath.

I tried to use caret ^ symbol also with the for /F
command, and it is not possible to break the line like
with the pathname in the type command line in a way,
that the command returns a output from the Textfile.

My question is, is there a way to get a echo output
with the `for /F` command, when the pathname is broken
with a caret or similar symbol instead of using the Word
wrap?

I use Windows XP for my work with batchfiles.

Wishes Stefan :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I have to mention that quotation like `type C:\"Dokumente und Einstellungen"\Textdokument.txt` is a terrible bad habbit; you should always quote the whole path like `type "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Textdokument.txt"`.

The caret `^` is not recognised as the escape character when it appears in a quoted portion, so this cannot work:

```cmd
for /F "usebackq" %%A in ("C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\^
Textdokument.txt") do echo %%A
```

But you could escape the quotation marks, then it would work:

```cmd
for /F "usebackq" %%A in (^"C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\^
Textdokument.txt^") do echo %%A
```

However, escaped quotation marks expose the path to the parser unquoted, of course, so you need to be aware of the fact that this could cause troubles with some special characters, like `&`, `(`, `)`, `^`.

Moreover, the above command line actually escapes the first character `T` of the second line. This is not a problem here as `T` is nothing special, but there might be problematic situations though.

You must not place <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> before the `^` or at the beginning of the following line, because they are then treated as part of the specified path.

Anyway, let me suggest another way that is safe and requires no escaping:

```cmd
for /F "usebackq" %%A in (
    "C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\Textdokument.txt"
) do echo %%A
```

Comment: My consent could be, to use a path in brackets for readability with a second line feed it can be changed to a : abstract variable environment variables or parameterlists. The point of view is that escaping is a request for a line readability. I am aware that bad habits can lead to misguided information links. To stay out of remote control services my circuit language in use is not a habit.

Answer (score -1):

Like you, I found that:

```
for /F "usebackq" %%A in ("C:\Users\myusername\" ^
   "foo.txt") do echo %%A
```

Doesn't work.  However, a workaround might be:

```
SET MYDIR = "c:\Users\myusername\"

for /F "usebackq" %%A in (%MYDIR% ^
   "foo.txt") do echo %%A
```

This works for me.

Comment: With the spaces that must be supplied, between _MYDIR =_

Comment: and ^    "foo.txt", here the space must be a tab space.

Comment: I have to look from a different view, my question is still not solved. "foo.txt" can be only viewed in a homepath or homefile %MYDIR% has no effect. The line break is just possible because of the brackets used in the for /F command line. Instead i could also wrote without caret symbol for /F "usebackq" %%A in (%HAHA% "Textdokument.txt") do echo %%A